Showing that $f_k = f \chi_{B(0,k)}$ has compact essential support.
Consider the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f$ denote a $p-$locally integrable function, that is,
$$ \int_K |f(x)|^p \, dx < \infty,  \quad \forall \text{ compact set } K \subset \mathbb R^n.$$
For each $k \in \mathbb N$, define the function $f_k \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ by
$$ f_k(x) = f(x)\chi_{B(0,k)}(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^n. $$
GOAL. My objective is to prove that $f_k$ is compactly supported (one should note that here we're dealing with the essential support of $f_k$ and not the usual support), for every $k \in \mathbb N$.
My attempt. By definition of essential support, we have that
$$ \text{ess sup} (f_k) := \mathbb R^n \setminus \bigcup \{ \Omega \subset \mathbb R^n \, \colon \, \Omega \text{ is open and } f_k = 0 \text{ a.e. on } \Omega \}. $$
Since $\text{ess sup} (f_k) \subset \mathbb R^n$, all we have to do is to prove that it is closed and bounded (Heine-Borel theorem). Moreover, taking into account that any union of open sets is again open, we know that
$$ \bigcup \{ \Omega \subset \mathbb R^n \, \colon \, \Omega \text{ is open and } f_k = 0 \text{ a.e. on } \Omega \} $$
is open, so that $\text{ess sup}(f_k)$ is a closed set. Therefore, everything that is left to prove is that it is bounded,i.e., that there exists a ball $B(x,r) \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $\text{ess sup} (f_k) \subset B(x,r)$, where $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $r > 0$. For this I thought about the obvious choice $x = 0$ and $r = k$, which yield the inclusion
$$ \text{ ess sup} (f_k) \subset B(0,k). $$
Now, I am having a hard time analysing this set inclusion. Perhaps someone can help me with this?

The inclusion $ess\ supp \ f_k \subseteq B(0,k)$ is not true in general, only $ess\ sup \ f_k \subseteq \overline{ B(0,k) }$ can be proven.
Take $\Omega = \mathbb R^n \setminus \overline{ B(0,k) }$, which is open. Moreover, $f_k$ is zero on $\Omega$. This implies that
$$
\mathbb R^n \setminus ess\ supp \ f_k \supseteq \Omega,
$$
and
$$
ess\ supp \ f_k \subseteq\mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega = \overline{ B(0,k) }.
$$

Your reasoning is correct but I have a question. This also implies that $\text{ ess supp } (f_k)$ is bounded because (for example) $\overline{B(0,k)} \subset B(0,k+1)$, am I right ?

yes of course..
